# javascript form validation - positioning

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have little snippet for validatin' my form. I need help to position the error messages, because now all message appear in the filed, so the user can't see it, and so its very annoying.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zőöüóúéáűí ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "<?php echo $lettersonly; ?>");  
    $("#regval").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength:30,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            nick: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength:12
            },
            pass1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            pass2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#pass1"
            },

          messages: {
            full: {
                required: ".....",
                minlength: "....",
                maxlength: "...."
            },
            nick: {
                required: "....",
                minlength: "....",
                maxlength: "...."
            },
            pass1: {
                required: "....",
                minlength: "..."
            },
            pass2: {
                required: "....",
                minlength: "....",
                equalTo: "...."
            },

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: exactly what do you mean by "all message appear in the filed". Please compare the behavior to http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"filed"?

Without really understanding where your error messages show up I suggest you check the documentation.

[jQuery Validation Plugin: Options Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

There are several options/methods you can use to modify the default error generation / placement of the plugin.

`errorElement`: if the error shouldn't be a label

`wrapper` & `errorLabelContainer`: If you e.g. want a ul/li's somewhere specific where all errors should show instead of being placed right near the input field which has the error

`errorPlacement` (function): Called exactly once when the input validated has an error. With this function you can place the error element where ever you want. All subsequent error messages for the same input are shown in the same place afterwards